# Patching to remove index update strategies

Tags: configuration, content-search

While configuring cd instance on SOLR one has to **remove** index update strategies and **set to manual** from index definitions on cd server.

*Can we do that using sitecore patching?*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `<patch:delete />` to achieve this. It will look like:

```xml
<sitecore>
  <contentSearch>
      <configuration>
        <indexes>
          <index id="xxxxx">
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
                <patch:delete />
            </strategies>
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy"> 
                <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies‌​/manual" /> 
            </strategies>
            </index>    
        </indexes>
    </configuration>    
  </contentSearch>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: thanks, this would look like that if I want to add manual strategy: 
`<strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
       <patch:delete/>
      </strategies>
      <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
       <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/manual" />
      </strategies>` / can you add that to an answer please?

Comment: Hey @AndreyBobrov, what do you mean? You question asked to "remove index update strategies". Do you have multiple <strategies> elements?

Comment: in order to disable the strategy you have to set it to manual as well, please check my question

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: Answer amended.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the original strategy and add strategy with same name just using `ManualStrategy` type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <indexUpdateStrategies>
          <intervalAsyncMaster>
            <patch:delete />
          </intervalAsyncMaster>
          <intervalAsyncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.ManualStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        </indexUpdateStrategies>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You need to repeat that for all the strategies.

Thanks to that you don't worry how many indexes there are and if anyone else adds a new index later. They will use manual on CD servers always.

Comment: I consider this quite dangerous and confusing. the below answer is more correct for my case. However removing asyncMaster strategy is a good practice for cd env

Comment: I don't understand why you say it's dangerous. CD servers should NEVER update indexes when you use Solr. It's safer than you expect ;)

Comment: I like this more than the accepted answer. This is preventative. Anyone who adds another index will automatically be set to manual. Unless they have a custom strategy.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAuer