# Index sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web was not found exception Sitecore 9 XP1 scaled

Tags: content-search, configuration

I have a distributed Sitecore 9 Update 2 XP1 on prem setup. Getting below exception only on the CD servers, upon refresh the error goes away. Any ideas to resolve this?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Index sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web was not found Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException: Index
>   sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web was not found
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [IndexNotFoundException: Index sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web was
>   not found]
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name) +127
>   Sitecore.Marketing.Search.Observers.Activation.UpdateSearchIndexObserver`1..ctor(ILogger`1
>   logger, String databaseName, String searchIndex) +302
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +339
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +116
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +111
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.TransientCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +30
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +111
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +116
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +111
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +116
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +111
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider) +116
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider) +127
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type type) +69
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode
>   configNode, Boolean assert) +483
>
> [ConfigurationException: Could not create object from service provider
>   . Config XML: ]
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode
>   configNode, Boolean assert) +646
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +138
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   Boolean assert) +68
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode
>   processorNode) +91
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode
>   processorNode) +145
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters) +138
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +480
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
>   +285    Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnPostAuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase
>   context) +214    Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs )
>   +335    System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +139    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +197    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +88

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why it can't find the index, however it's best practice to avoid having the CD server(s) do any indexing and leave that to another role.
This is to leave the CD server resources for doing actual content delivery instead of other background tasks such as indexing.

See [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3918/patching-to-remove-index-update-strategies) for a good post on how to do this with patch configs.

Comment: I understand that this question was similar to the one already being asked before, this essentially is not a duplicate question. We did reach out to sitecore support and they recognized this as an issue with the scaled XP1 installation for sitecore 9.0 update 2. They have a patch for this now, below are the details -Patch: Sitecore.Support.255663
Version: 9.0.2.2
Revision: 181115


Description

UpdateSearchIndexObserver may fail at construction

Compatibility - Sitecore

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question so you can add the correct answer.

Comment: It's still a duplicate question. The answer needs to be added to the one we already have in place - that covers all other bases. When new information around an existing answer arises, additional answers should be added to the existing question.